# Bootstrap align svg in center of header

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4

I copied this card template from bootstrap for a warning card. At the header of the card, I'm using an svg that I got from Bootstrap's icons https://icons.getbootstrap.com/icons/exclamation-triangle-fill/. There, you can see some examples where the icon is implemented properly. The icon is aligned exactly in the middle next to the next. However, in my code the icon is aligned at the bottom and so is not centered. Is there a way to fix this?

```
 <div class="card" style="width: 18rem;">
    <div class="card-body">
                <div class="mb-3">
                    <h5 class="card-title">
                        <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="16" height="16" fill="currentColor" viewBox="0 0 16 16">
                            <path fill-rule="evenodd" d="M8.982 1.566a1.13 1.13 0 0 0-1.96 0L.165 13.233c-.457.778.091 1.767.98 1.767h13.713c.889 0 1.438-.99.98-1.767L8.982 1.566zM8 5a.905.905 0 0 0-.9.995l.35 3.507a.552.552 0 0 0 1.1 0l.35-3.507A.905.905 0 0 0 8 5zm.002 6a1 1 0 1 0 0 2 1 1 0 0 0 0-2z"/>
                        </svg>
                        Warning
                    </h5>
                </div>
                <p class="card-text">
                    Text of card
                </p>

  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Add class or id to svg icon and in css set negative margin-top to it. Like this `margin-top: -5px;`

Comment: Check this https://jsfiddle.net/1bLdq8js/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use negative `margin-top` to adjust it.

For example:

```
 <div class="card" style="width: 18rem;">
<div class="card-body">
            <div class="mb-3">
                <h5 class="card-title">
                    <svg class="myIcon" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="16" height="16" fill="currentColor" viewBox="0 0 16 16">
                        <path fill-rule="evenodd" d="M8.982 1.566a1.13 1.13 0 0 0-1.96 0L.165 13.233c-.457.778.091 1.767.98 1.767h13.713c.889 0 1.438-.99.98-1.767L8.982 1.566zM8 5a.905.905 0 0 0-.9.995l.35 3.507a.552.552 0 0 0 1.1 0l.35-3.507A.905.905 0 0 0 8 5zm.002 6a1 1 0 1 0 0 2 1 1 0 0 0 0-2z"/>
                    </svg>
                    Warning
                </h5>
            </div>
            <p class="card-text">
                Text of card
            </p>
        </div>
    </div>
```

CSS:

```
.myIcon { margin-top: -5px; }
```

Check it here: https://jsfiddle.net/8t61qehn/

Comment: That works, but I was just wondering if there was a general solution to this kind of stuff. This requires me to know the exact pixels and measurements. Is there a solution that worked for all images regardless of whether they were 16x16?

Answer (score 0):

[My Result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QgFAs.png)

Just change first `DIV` style with `text-align: center`
Check the image from above make sure that way you want show
drop like if work for you.

Comment: That wasn't really what I wanted. You see that the image is still aligned at the bottom. One way to check if it's not centered is that you zoom in on the page a bunch. When it starts looking messed up, then it is not centered.

Comment: Oh Now i got it .. just give parent div margin-top = value .. its will be as  your wish browser center or other method is using FLEXBOX Properties

Answer (score 0):

printf("%d\n", 42);  /* You can simply add some css on style part in  as follows: */

```
   .card-svg {
    position: absolute;
    left: 50%;
    transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  }
  .card-txt{
    position: absolute;
    top: 50%;
    left: 50%;
    transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
    text-align: center;
  }
```

/*And add this styles as classes on your HTML code as follows:  */

```
<img class="card-svg" src="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="16" height="16" fill="currentColor" viewBox="0 0 16 16">
                              <path fill-rule="evenodd" d="M8.982 1.566a1.13 1.13 0 0 0-1.96 0L.165 13.233c-.457.778.091 1.767.98 1.767h13.713c.889 0 1.438-.99.98-1.767L8.982 1.566zM8 5a.905.905 0 0 0-.9.995l.35 3.507a.552.552 0 0 0 1.1 0l.35-3.507A.905.905 0 0 0 8 5zm.002 6a1 1 0 1 0 0 2 1 1 0 0 0 0-2z"/>
                          <img>
 <h5 class="card-txt">Warning</h5>
```

/*By the way i changed the svg into img you can try like that if this is what you want.*/